# After installing lubuntu-desktop, it says it's Lubuntu when starting up. How can I revert this back to normal?

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments

Instead of this: [ubuntu splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmdEi.png)

It shows this:  [lubuntu splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD19F.png)

How do I revert this?

Comment: I haven't bothered with customizing the splash screen in a very long time, but I found this with a quick search.

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/customize-boot-splash-screen-logo-linux/

Comment: @Gerowen please see my answer for an easier, standardized, way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll be using the `update-alternatives` command. But first we'll look at a snippet from the man page...

man update-alternatives

```
   When using the --config option, update-alternatives will  list  all  of
   the  choices  for  the  link  group  of  which given name is the master
   alternative name.  The current choice is marked with a ‘*’.   You  will
   then  be prompted for your choice regarding this link group.  Depending
   on the choice made, the link group might no longer be in auto mode. You
   will  need to use the --auto option in order to return to the automatic
   mode (or you  can  rerun  --config  and  select  the  entry  marked  as
   automatic).
```

To see how it's currently set, in `terminal`, type:

`ls -al /etc/alternatives/*plymouth*`

You'll see something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Apr 21 12:46 default.plymouth -> /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Apr 21 12:46 default.plymouth.grub -> /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Apr 21 12:45 text.plymouth -> /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth
```

You should note that my example symlinks actually show what you'll end up with, after executing the following commands. With each command, you'll be asked to select which boot screens you wish, and you'll be selecting the Ubuntu screens, instead of the Lubuntu screens (as they are currently set).

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

<strike>`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth.grub`</strike>

`sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth`

Comment: When I run: `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth.grub` it outputs:
`update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for default.plymouth.grub`
All the others work fine, though.

Comment: @Tem326 that one may get set with the first command. Check by using the ls command that I gave earlier, and verify that all of the symlinks look like my examples. I'll update my answer.